# products_group = df[['CustomerID', 'StockCode']].groupby('CustomerID').count().sort_values('StockCode', axis=0, ascending=False)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas-groupby, data-analysis

Can somebody please explain this piece of code to me ?

```
products_group = df[['CustomerID', 'StockCode']].groupby('CustomerID').count().sort_values('StockCode', axis=0, ascending=False)
```

I understood that it is trying to create a dataframe and groupby with the help of the groupby function but after that I am not able to understand the code

Comment: @itachi-uchiha12 Could you please change the title. Your title could be more descriptive and focus on one issue, not just show a line of code possibly out of context.

Comment: @oaxacamatt I am really sorry this was the first time I posted a question !! Would take care the next time !! Thanks !!